# Bundle doesnt loading when i return from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-lifecycle, android-bundle

Hi I have an application and it has 2 fragments HomeFragment and ListFragment and also DetailActivity and UpdateActivity and AddActivity and when I go from fragment ListFragment to UpdateActivity | DetailActivity then HomeFragment saves the Bundle, and when I navigate back it doesn't load the Bundle (Also I erase extra Activities so they don't double up)

[image: Problem image]

Comment: What do you mean by "save the `Bundle`" and "load the `Bundle`"? Please show some code and indicate where the problem is.

Comment: ```
D/ContentValues: onPause: Bundle[{breakfast=2, dinner=3, lunch=1}]
D/ContentValues: onPauseButSet with "setArguments()": Bundle[{breakfast=2, dinner=3, lunch=1}]
D/ContentValues: getArguments + restoreData: null
D/ContentValues: onCreateView + getArguments: null
```

Comment: Hi, please do not put code or log snippets in comments. These cannot be formatted properly and are not readable. Just edit your question and add the code snippets and/or log output there.

Comment: Also, the logs are not usable without seeing the code that generates the logs. Please edit your question and post the relevant parts of the code. We aren't mind readers ;-)

Comment: I fixed the problem, i just use SharedPreferences instead of SavedInstanceState